# Calling service B from service A for authentication and authorization

Tags: node.js, architecture, microservices

I have service `Ticketing` and a service `Auth`.

Not everyone is allowed to perform CRUD on tickets.

When a request comes to perform an action the ticket, I need to check if the user has proper right.

For that I need to communicate to service `Auth` which holds roles and endpoints of allowed permissions on the resource for a user.

How can I make this call?

1. Should I make sync call? i.e. Direct call from service A to B?
2. Use event bus

Or any other possible ways?

Also, there are some tables that is needed from `Auth` service to join with `Ticketing` service to fetch data.

How this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Given the microservices tag, I assume `Ticketing` and `Auth` are separate microservices.

I am also assuming, based on description, that each has it's own API.

What's not quite clear, is how the user accessed the `Ticketing` service.  Were they authenticated first (e.g. if a human user via a web application, did they login first, prior to being directed to `Ticketing` in some manner).

I assume a login was performed first.

An approach might be

1. At the point of user login (or caller if non-human) obtain the list of authorizations the user has access to via the `Auth` service.
2. Store the authorizations within the HTTP Authorization header
3. As each microservice is called, it then only need (synchronously) ask the `Auth` service to validate the list of authorizations is correct.

An appropriate technology approach is [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction).
In the scenario described above, when `Auth` is first called to authenticate the user/caller, the authorizations could be returned within the `sub` claim, or you could create your own claim to determine authorizations used.

As the user/caller moves through different microservices, a syncrhonous call to the `Auth` service need only be made to validate the user/caller is authorized.

Synchronous or asynchronous: regardless of direct call/event bus, if an authorization check is required, it needs to complete before the calling service takes action.  Otherwise it may expose data / modify it, when the caller did not have authorization.

Joining tables: in a microservice pattern, this is not likely to be wise.  Rather, obtain the data required from the `Auth` service via an API call and use that with the calling service (e.g. `Ticketing`).